# C# TCP Connection Uses too Much Memory when Receiving Deserialized Classes

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, tcp, memory-leaks

I'm trying to make a C # client / server program that can send classes between two programs (on the same computer or on different computers) by serializing them, deserializing them, and sending them over TCP but I don't know why the program is using too much memory. After a few seconds of execution, the programs (client and server) reach BOTH 100MB and the memory used continues to increase. I tried to use both the TCP connection and the Named Pipes, but the problem is still the same. So I assume it's a problem (maybe) in serialization and deserialization, but I don't know. Would you have any ideas?

Class for serialization and deserialization:

```
class ObjectSerializer {
    public ObjectSerializer() { }

    public MemoryStream Serialize(Object obj, Type[] types) {
        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Object), types);

        xmlSerializer.Serialize(memoryStream, obj);
        return memoryStream;
    }

    public Object Deserialize(MemoryStream memoryStream, Type[] types) {
        XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Object), types);
        return (Object)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(memoryStream);
    }
}
```

Class containing methods used to send and receive messages and classes:

```
class TCPMethods {
    private NetworkStream networkStream;

    private Type[] types;

    //Constructor receiving a socket
    public TCPMethods(Socket socket, Type[] types) {
        this.networkStream = new NetworkStream(socket);
        this.types = types;

    }

    //Constructor receiving a stream 
    public TCPMethods(NetworkStream networkStream, Type[] types) {
        this.networkStream = networkStream;
        this.types = types;

    }


    /*  
     *  
     *  FUNCTIONS THAT SEND AND RECEIVE DATA THROUGH THE NETWORKSTREAM 
     *
     */


    public void SendMessage(String message) {
        //I serialize the message and send it 
        byte[] serializedMessage = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);
        networkStream.Write(serializedMessage, 0, serializedMessage.Length);

    }

    public void SendObject(Object obj) {
        ObjectSerializer convertObject = new ObjectSerializer();

        //I call the class function to serialize the object and send it 
        byte[] serializedObject = convertObject.Serialize(obj, types).ToArray();
        //Calculate and send the length of the byte array            byte[] objectLenght = BitConverter.GetBytes(serializedObject.Length);

        networkStream.Write(objectLenght, 0, objectLenght.Length);
        networkStream.Write(serializedObject, 0, serializedObject.Length);

    }

    public String ReceiveMessage() {
        //String in which the complete message will be inserted 
        String completeMessage = String.Empty;
        //Byte array in which I save the message I am going to read from the stream 
        byte[] messageBuffer = new byte[512];

        do {
            //I read and save the bytes of the message from the stream
            networkStream.Read(messageBuffer, 0, messageBuffer.Length);
            //I convert to string and concatenate the message part 
            completeMessage += Encoding.UTF8.GetString(messageBuffer);
            //I clear the byte buffer 
            messageBuffer = new byte[512];
            //I repeat until I finish reading the message 
        } while (networkStream.DataAvailable);

        return completeMessage;
    }

    public Object ReceiveObject() {
        ObjectSerializer convertObject = new ObjectSerializer();
        //I declare and read the variable which contains the length of the object
        byte[] objectLenght = new byte[sizeof(int)];
        networkStream.Read(objectLenght, 0, objectLenght.Length);

        //Array in which the object will be saved 
        byte[] objectBuffer = new byte[BitConverter.ToInt32(objectLenght, 0)];

        //I read and save the bytes of the message from the stream
        networkStream.Read(objectBuffer, 0, objectBuffer.Length); ;
        //I resize the array and just keep the bytes read 
        Array.Resize(ref objectBuffer, objectBuffer.Length);

        //Deserialize and returns object
        return convertObject.Deserialize(new MemoryStream(objectBuffer), types);
    }
}
```

Comment: *"memory used continues to increase"* - do you run out of memory? It could be totally normal what you observe. See [GC topic on msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/fundamentals#memory-release).

Comment: No, I don't run out of memory, but I reach GBs of memory used. The fact is that I'm not storing the data received, I'm just printing in on the console

Comment: Try closing the Network Stream.

Comment: I can't close the stream because i need to constantly send objects via TCP. If I close the stream the connection is interrupted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found what was wrong. Basically the Garbage Collector isn't able to dispose the XMLConverter if the istance was created with that type of constructor

```
new XmlSerializer(type, otherTypes);
```

Instead of that class, I have used the Json serializer contained in the package Newtonsoft.Json. It now works well and it is way much faster!